# Dudando entre manejar un solo archivo de texto o múltiples.¿fseek() en loop o fopen()/fclose()?

Tags: c

Es una pregunta puramente teórica. Si tengo una estructura que alberga 4 datos (NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, EDAD, SIGUIENTE), ¿qué es preferible para almacenar las estructuras de los distintos usuarios?

- una sola hoja de texto en la cual el dato "SIGUIENTE" guarde la localización del otro usuario para ser utilizada por fseek "hacia arriba" y comprobar así si el usuario está ya registrado
- múltiples archivos de texto en los cuales el dato "SIGUIENTE" contenga la dirección de un archivo de texto distinto para abrirlo con `fopen()` y cerrarlo con `fclose()`.

  - NOMBRE: TOMÁS
  - APELLIDOS: GÓMEZ TOBÍAS
  - EDAD: 24
  - SIGUIENTE: `fopen()`/`fclose()` o `fseek()`

Comment: Las operaciones de I/O son costosas, por lo que me imagino que moverse dentro de un fichero debe ser más rápido que estar abriendo y cerrando ficheros continuamente... pero llevo bastante tiempo sin trabajar con eso, así que puede que me equivoque. ¿Has probado a hacer una pequeña prueba para ver los resultados?

Comment: En ello estoy Álvaro, pensé lo mismo que tu, estaba haciéndolo con múltiples ficheros pero de pronto me di cuenta de que debía ser más rápido con un solo fichero moviendo el cursor dentro de él, el riesgo que tengo es un contador que es modificado cada vez que el usuario introduce los datos que al ser modificado colocando el cursor con fseek() y variando la información con fprintf() podría producir un error en el archivo completo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Como siempre @eferion se lleva mi +1, gran trabajo. Pero he de informar a @IvanSoler que los índices y su gestión es sólo una parte de los SGBD, quizá te sea más sencillo usar un servidor `MySQL`, `postgresql`, etc para almacenar tus datos y delegar en él la gestión de los datos, índices, acceso a datos, etc.

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias por aportar ese complemento

Comment: Hay bibliotecas de funciones (como `sqlite`) que te permiten trabajar con bases de datos basadas en archivos de manera muy sencilla. Valora los pros y los contras de hacer tú la implementación o usar algo que ya está usado, probado y probablemente esté mucho más optimizado y libre de errores. Aquí tienes un mini tutorial: https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**¿Tiene sentido almacenar un puntero a la siguiente ubicación?**

Lo cierto es que no. No solo porque los datos ya se encuentran en posiciones consecutivas de memoria sino que hay que tener en cuenta otros factores:

- Si se elimina un registro hay que recalcular un número indeterminado de punteros
- Si se inserta un registro hay que recalcular un número indeterminado de punteros
- Si los punteros fuerzan saltos en el fichero (el registro 1 apunta como siguiente al registro 45) se rompe la localidad de los datos y eso obliga al sistema a repaginar la caché, lo que impacta muy negativamente en el rendimiento
- Si algo sale mal se pueden provocar listas circulares o podemos tener registros huérfanos (existen pero nadie los enlaza como siguiente).

Entonces... ¿Cómo se podría hacer?

Como norma general lo más sencillo suele ser el mejor camino para empezar. Supongamos que, en base a los datos de tu pregunta, tenemos una estructura tal que:

```
struct Datos
{
  char nombre[50];
  char apellidos[100];
  int edad;
};
```

Si se guardan los datos en formato binario lo normal es que cada registro ocupe 154 bytes (en algunas plataformas puede ocupar 152), pero siempre será `sizeof(struct Datos)`. Si suponemos que el tamaño es finalmente 154 bytes los registros se almacenarán en el fichero de la siguiente forma:

- offset 0: primer registro
- offset 154: segundo registro
- offset 308: tercer registro
- ...

Si no almacenamos una cantidad insultante de datos, la lectura secuencial es la mejor solución: fácil de implementar y con tiempos de acceso relativamente cortos. Un ejemplo de búsqueda:

```
while(1)
{
  struct Datos temp;
  fread(&temp,sizeof(struct Datos),1,fich);
  if( feof(fich) )
  {
    // Final del fichero
  }
  else if( strcmp(temp.nombre,"pepito") )
  {
    // Tenemos el registro buscado
  }
  // ...
}
```

La búsqueda secuencial tiene como inconveniente que ante un volumen grande de datos, localizar un elemento que se encuentra al final del fichero puede requerir bastante tiempo... La solución en estos casos suele ser la misma que la aplicada en los motores de bases de datos y consiste en crear índices. La estructura, diseño y cantidad de índices dependerán de los requisitos a aplicar en las búsquedas, pero un ejemplo sencillo podría ser tener un segundo fichero en el que se almacenasen los índices de los registros, ordenados éstos por nombre. Un ejemplo práctico:

datos.txt

```
NOMBRE            
roberto
pedro
valentín
sergio
```

indice_nombre.ind

```
1
0
3
2
```

Ahora se podrían aplicar algoritmos de búsqueda sobre el índice. Por ejemplo... si por ejemplo el nombre empieza por `z` se podría recorrer el índice en sentido inverso para encontrar el registro sin tener que recorrer todo el fichero.

**¿Tiene sentido tener el registro dividido en varios ficheros?**

Si volvemos a fijarnos en el diseño de bases de datos nos encontramos con que, en ocasiones, es necesario acceder a varias tablas para recuperar toda la información referente a algo.

Esas tablas suelen expresar algún tipo de relación entre los datos (por ejemplo, una persona puede tener 0 o más coches a su nombre. Esta relación sería complicada de gestionar con un único fichero).

El tema de las bases de datos en general y el de las bases de datos en particular daría para un millar de respuestas como estas, o más. Internet está a rebosar de libros y documentación al respecto así que sería interesante que, si el tema te resulta atractivo, empieces a navegar en busca de toda esa documentación.

**¿Y qué tal si tenemos los datos en memoria?**

La memoria es muchísimo más rápida que los ficheros. Si es posible llevar los datos a consultar a la memoria conseguiremos reducir enormemente los tiempos de consulta. De hecho los motores gráficos suelen tener una serie de registros cacheados con la idea de no tener que acudir a los ficheros para recuperar dicha información.

Por otro lado hay que tener en cuenta que la memoria no es un sistema persistente. Si se va la luz o se cierra la aplicación el contenido de la memoria se perderá. Es importante por tanto no perder de vista que los datos habría que llevarlos cada cierto tiempo a un dispositivo persistente (como un fichero) para evitar la pérdida de información.

Comment: Asombroso, déjame unas horas para procesar la información antes de cerrar la pregunta. Una cosa más, si tuviese un elemento variable dentro de cada estructura como podría ser un contador de visitas es recomendable utilizar fseek() al punto en el que se encentra y luego fprintf para modificarlo? 
Gracias.

Comment: @IvanSoler no suele haber una solución única para cada problema... Aun así me da la sensación de que estás intentando ir demasiado rápido. Primero céntrate en controlar la gestión de los ficheros y después lánzate en busca de nuevas aventuras

Comment: Gracias iré paso por paso !

Comment: Hola @eferion no sé qué ocurre pero cuando procedo a hacer un printf() con los datos guardados en el archivo binario con el tamaño de la estructura creada los últimos números de un array que tengo no aparecen pero cuando añado 5 bytes al tamaño creado y el solicitado el problema se resuelve... alguna idea?

Comment: @IvanSoler presumiblemente esa duda debería ir en una pregunta nueva